# Sass inserting an unwanted space in formula

Tags: sass

Simple one this (hopefully with a simple solution).

Sass is compiling this....

```
font-size:(30/13)em;
```

into this....

```
font-size: 2.30769 em;
```

The space before the em makes it invalid and Chrome ignores it.

Any ideas?

(oh and before anybody asks why I'm dividing one number by another, I've simplified a formula to make the question simpler, normally there would be variables in there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I think you can use:

```
font-size:(30em/13);
```

to fix this. (At least, that's what compiles properly in Sass for me.) Although, if you're using variables, that could change things (if you can't have the `em` inside of the variable).

In which case, you could try:

```
font-size:$var*1em;
```

Which works out when Sass compiles it on my machine.